# How do I ensure consistent alignment of textboxes in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to set my fields and textboxes to be aligned consistently in HTML, but I'm not familiar with doing so yet as I'm new to HTML and CSS. Here's what I'm trying to achieve:[image]

And here is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        
            p {
            font-size:16px
            }
            
            input {
            font-size:inherit;
            }
            
        </style>
        
        <script>
        
        </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <br>
    <br>
        <p>Name:<input type="text"  id="nameTextBox"/></p>
        <p>Age:<input type="number"  id="ageBox" min="0"/></p>
        <p>Gender<input type="radio" name="genderRadioButton" value="male"/>Male
                    <input type="radio" name ="genderRadioButton" value="female"/>Female</p>
                
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Use Combination of `<label>` and `<input>` inside your `<p>` Put your Text inside label elements and set your label to `float: left` and input to `float: right`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Use a `<span>` element with a fixed width around the Name, Age and Gender labels.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            p {
            font-size:16px
            }
            
            input {
            font-size:inherit;
            }
            
            span {
              width: 200px;
              display: inline-block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <br>
    <br>
        <p><span>Name:</span><input type="text"  id="nameTextBox"/></p>
        <p><span>Age:</span><input type="number"  id="ageBox" min="0"/></p>
        <p>
            <span>Gender:</span>
            <input type="radio" name="genderRadioButton" value="male"/>Male
            <input type="radio" name ="genderRadioButton" value="female"/>Female
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to achieve the same, like using `<table>`, `float`, `flex`. Below is the flex one. I'll add the other ones if you need them.

```css
.container{
  width:300px;
}

.row{
  display:flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}

.row>*{
  flex:1
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input name="name" />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label>Id:</label>
    <input name="id" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
     <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        
            p {
            font-size:16px
            ;
            }
            
            input {
            font-size:inherit;
            }
            #nameTextBox{
                margin-left: 9.2%;

            }
            #ageBox{
                margin-left: 10%;

            }
            span{
                margin-left: 8.1%;
            }
           
            
        

    
        </style>
        
        <script>
        
        </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <br>
    <br>
        <p>Name:<input type="text"  id="nameTextBox"/></p>
        <p>Age:<input type="number"  id="ageBox" min="0"/></p>
        <p>Gender<span><input type="radio" name="genderRadioButton" value="male"/>Male
                    <input type="radio" name ="genderRadioButton" value="female"/>Female</p>
        </span>   
    </body>
    
</html>
```